# How to use selected ComboBox Item as a reference in a formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which have several static sheets in it but it also requires user to import some sheets and I don't know how many sheets they will import. The imported sheets will all have the same format.

I am trying to develop a formula that could use the imported sheet name as a reference so that the formula could look up the data in the imported sheets.

Now I have a dynamic comboBox which has all the sheets name on it. I am trying to write a code that let me grab the user selected sheets(from the comboBox) and then use it in the formula.

I found the following code on the website, however instead of certain objects, I have a dynamic number of object(sheets)

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim sheetName as ComboBox
Dim shtName as String

Set ws = Worksheets("Analysis Sheet")
Set sheetName = ws.OLEObjects("NameFromActiveXProperties").Object

shtName = sheetName.Value
```

Due to company policy, I cannot upload the worksheets I have.

One of the formulas I have is =MATCH('Analysis Sheet'!$A$9&"*",***shtName***!$A$10:$A$136)
where shtName is the variable that I want to set as the refernce for selected item from the ComboBox.
Could anyone help me with this?

I am not good at describing questions. Please let me know if there is anything that is not clear.
Thank you very much!

Help appreicated!!!

Comment: A formula cannot (easily) look up multiple sheets of data. If you are going to use multipla sheets you need to do this with VBA, either by writing a function to get the results you want, or writing a User-Defined Function that takes in an array of values and returns something from each sheet in that array (sum, product, whatever). Without more information, it is impossible to answer how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you could use here.  The easiest is to use the `INDIRECT` worksheet function in combination with your function that returns the sheet name (which you have only implicitly named here):

```
=MATCH('Analysis Sheet'!$A$9 & "*", INDIRECT("'" & shtName() & "'" & "!$A$10:$A$136"))
```

Alternatively, you could modify your shtName function:

```
Public Function shtName(SheetRange as string) as range
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim sheetName as ComboBox
    Dim shtName as String

    Set ws = Worksheets("Analysis Sheet")
    Set sheetName = ws.OLEObjects("NameFromActiveXProperties").Object

    shtName = worksheets(sheetName.Value).Range(SheetRange)
End Function
```

... And use it thus:

```
=MATCH('Analysis Sheet'!$A$9&"*", shtName("$A$10:$A$136"))
```